# Ubuntu cant open .deb files - how can I correct this?

Tags: games, deb, steam

I've downloaded Ubuntu because my Windows 7 kept showing a black screen with a cursor on it and and wouldn't boot up properly. So I thought that maybe Linux would work.

It worked perfectly but I can't open `.deb` files, which should be made for Ubuntu.
Also, If i try to download Steam 64-bit, it tells me an error and can't download it. I don't know why since it's made for Ubuntu.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried installing Steam via `apt` in a Terminal?

Answer (score 7):

For a start, download the [Steam Client](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb).

After that, you need to navigate to the location you saved the `steam_latest.deb` file.
By default your downloaded files are stored in `/Downloads` folder.

Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`cd /Downloads`

Next to install it type:

`sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Now a new windows will pop out as in the image below:

[image: Steam]

Click on the button *Start Steam*.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your info, Steam has a limited number of games ready for Linux. Even if you install Steam, you might not get to see your entire collection of games under Ubuntu.

I would install Steam directly from their site: [Steam Linux](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/)

Regarding your inability to open .deb files, we need more info. It might be a number of reasons. Go into the command line, and copy the error message. Usually it tells more. When you double click on a .deb file, and it fails to execute due to whatever reason, you will not always see the error message.

Answer (score 1):

fix for corrupt deb package for steam client:

1) Download steam.deb via console

```
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
```

2) Install realpath

```
sudo apt-get install realpath
```

3) Install

```
steam sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to reinstall the software-center with the terminal ("I like you terminal!").

Purge USC and reinstall it (two seperate commands):

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Answer "Y" (YES) when he asks you.

IF you got (this is NOT a command for running):
"`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`",

just run:

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

As he say ^^ .