# Why can't I install Steam in Ubuntu Win7 ntfs partition?

Tags: steam

I have Win7 and ubuntu partition in my laptotp. I downloaded Steam .deb package. 
I tried to install it by doubleclicking it, but it said:
Internal Error
The file “/home/djokosihono/Desktop/steam_latest.deb” could not be opened. 
And when I try to install it using Terminal, it said:
dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam_latest.deb

It also happened when I try to install Google Chrome.

Is there any solutions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use this answer to [intall](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256634/ubuntu-cant-open-deb-files-how-can-i-correct-this/256644#256644) steam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very good that you included the error message (dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install): package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64) Errors were encountered while processing: steam_latest.deb). From this the problem is fairly clear. You have a 64 bit processor but the package ist for 32 bit. So you need a different package.

But as Steam is now in the Ubuntu Software Center, that would be the way to go. In linux you never download programs manually. If it's not in the Ubuntu Software Center, you can almost always find a repository for ubuntu where you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should either download the 64bit version of the deb package or just install Steam from the Ubuntu Software-Center.

Comment: But when I try to install Steam from the software center, it says: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

steam64: Depends: steam (= 1.0.0.27ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed.
Is there any solutions?