# Why isn't Steam available in Ubuntu's software center?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, software-center, 64-bit, steam

[image]

I have a newly installed 12.04 64bit Ubuntu machine!
fully updated.

I couldn't find steam in software center.
looking for the steam 64bit client.

I've desktop also with 12.04 64bit, which has the steam client in the software center. well at least when I installed it.

did someone remove steam from the software center?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo update-software-center` , then search again.

Comment: sorry @NikTh none of those fixed it...

Comment: Follow the commands [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure#Step_9_Ubuntu_Software_Center_fails_to_open). See if problem solved.

Comment: Well , probably the commands above (at the link I pointed you) not needed. I just open my Software Center (Ubuntu 12.04.2 - fresh install) and steam is not there. Of course I've enabled the Canonical Partners repository. Maybe you should open a bug about this ?

Comment: @Alex I recently wrote a post, about how you can install _Steam_ in Ubuntu. Please follow [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256634/ubuntu-cant-open-deb-files-how-can-i-correct-this/256644#256644)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a 64-bit version of ubuntu you wont see steam in the official repos. Only the 32-bit version is officially supported. I had to get the .deb from steam's web site.

Answer (score 1):

Steam is no longer in the [official Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Until it reappears there, I would suggest installing Steam directly from Valve. If I remember, the .deb file that they provided will automatically add Valve repositories so that you can receive updates.

Comment: i edited that question to have a pic of the search result i get.

Comment: @Alex right, you have to click "Show 3 technical items" at the bottom. Then the `steam-launcher` package will appear.

Comment: idk this is only one of the three things that have a connection to steam. "Upload/download maps to/from a VALVe game server (Client)"

Comment: the other 2 where somegthing for "sl" and "jacktrip"

Comment: do i need a curtain ppa?

Comment: Okay, this is getting confusing. Just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam-launcher` in a terminal.

Comment: This is not an answer to the Original Question. Questioner here asks Why the Ubuntu Software Center not have in list the steam client , not how to install steam from terminal.

Comment: i'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: Also, the reason i included the terminal commmand was because Alex was getting confused, and wasn't understanding what I was saying, so I decided that the terminal would just be way easier.

Comment: @strugee your answer doesnt work, except for the terminal installation. the show technical button at the bottom doesnt show the steam installer. (like i said before).

Comment: @Alex hmm, sorry then. I really have no idea then, as it was definitely showing for me the last time I checked - although I suppose it's *possible* that it came from the Valve repos. I assumed not though, because there was also a `steam` package listed (which was directly from Valve).

Comment: @strugee i did have the beta on my desktop. thats probably why

Comment: @Alex no, that shouldn't interfere. The problem isn't on your end, it turns out that Steam isn't in the Ubuntu repositories anymore: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steam&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all. I would recommend installing Steam directly from Valve.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit, I realize that I don't see Steam in the software center anymore. I went to the official steam webpage, and downloaded the application. And installed it. It works fine. its a .deb file, which is easily installed. Btw on the website it is written to install steam on your pc, and it support ms Windows and Mac, but if you click on it using ubuntu it gives you a .deb file to install.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

if you install the repo as above then you will install the i386 32 bit steam.

It would be better to install the 64 bit deb file from the valve website if you have a 64 bit operating system.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the steps on the linked page below to add the repository.

I had the exact same symptoms as the OP.

Steam still not showing in Software Center though.

I am now logged in to Steam and downloading Half-Life, which I purchased Years ago.
Nice to see some continuity in account purchases!

[Instructions to add the Steam PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/steam)

Since Steam is no longer in the Ubuntu repositories it will never show up in Software Center. I find it preferable to have the Software Update maintain the local packages in as current a state as possible.  This is why I linked the page above.  Yes it takes a few terminal commands.

> Our packages are signed by "Valve Software LLC " You can add this key to your package manager with:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B05498B7`

> Setup repository with:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list'`

Now just

`sudo apt-get install steam`

The first command allows your system to verify that the package is digitally signed by Valve.  The second adds the Valve repository so apt-get can use it.  The third actually installs Steam.

I didn't want to search for the proper way to manually install the .deb package and this way allows me to keep steam updated with the rest of my system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, it would probably be better to install it from official repositories instead of a PPA.

Comment: This answer is a bit hard to follow.